# How to keep my drop-down menu properly aligned with my element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I created a drop-down menu that appears when I click on my text that contains the class trigger that allows to open the menu, but I have a problem. My page is responsive, so I need the menu is correctly aligned with the element: http://prntscr.com/7gw5ox

When I resize the page: http://prntscr.com/7gw5wd

My HTML code (down-down menu - placed at the bottom of my page):

```
    <div id="help-down-down-menu" class="drop-down-menu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="faq.php">Frequently Asked Questions</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="faq.php">Test</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="faq.php">Test</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="faq.php">Test</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Footer code with the text that contains the drop-down menu trigger:

```
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span class="drop-down-menu-trigger" id="help">Help</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <span id="footer-copyright">
                <a href="./..">Coded by Dylan - ©2015-2016</a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
(function($)
{
    $(".drop-down-menu-trigger").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".drop-down-menu").css({"visibility": "visible"});
    });
})(jQuery);
```

CSS:

```
.drop-down-menu
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 110px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150%;
    left: 500px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.drop-down-menu:after
{
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -15px;
    border: 15px solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-top-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.drop-down-menu a
{
    display: block;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 10px;
}

.drop-down-menu a:hover
{
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.drop-down-menu #faq:before
{
    content: "\f059";
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Try setting `margin` and `padding` of `drop-down-menu` to 0 and tell me if it works.

Comment: No, it doesn't. This is a problem with the absolute position, because the child is not positioned relatively to its parent, so I do not know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried positioning it relative if you haven't already? ?

Comment: @Uptop14 I know the solution to this, but could you pl. provide the css code for classes footer and also inside that. It will be more easy if you provide the working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) or link of the site.

Comment: demo here: http://nextgenfocus.com/test/

Comment: Is it alright ? If i change some of the HTML tags order, as this is the only correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your code like this:

**HTML** : After Footer Comments your HTML Code must be like this

```
<div class="drop-display">
    <div id="help-down-down-menu" class="drop-down-menu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="modal-window-trigger" name="modal-window-faq" id="faq" href="faq.php">Frequently Asked Questions</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="faq.php">Test</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="faq.php">Test</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="faq.php">Test</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>
      <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ADDED & UPDATED +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
            <li>
                <span class="drop-down-menu-trigger" id="help" onclick="getPos(this)">Help</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="drop-down-menu-trigger" id="test" onclick="getPos(this)">Help</span>
            </li>
      <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ADDED & UPDATED +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
        </ul>
        <span id="footer-copyright">
            <a href="./..">Coded by Dylan - ©2015-2016</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="modal-window-faq" class="modal-window">
    ...
    ...
    ... <!-- Same as your code is-->
</div>
<div id="expose-mask"></div>
<script src="javascript/scripts.js"></script>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

1) Added Class: drop-display,

2) Removed 1 drop-down-menu class as was repeating, and modified one.

```
.drop-display
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    //text-align: center; REMOVE THIS LINE
    position: absolute; /* CHANGED FROM absolute */
    z-index: 999;
}

.drop-down-menu // NO UPDATE HERE
{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 110px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
```

**JQuery**

1) Added line to **hide drop-down-menu on page load**

2) Modified code of **Visibility to fadeIn() OR fadeToggle()**

```
$(".drop-down-menu").hide(); // On very first line of scripts.js file
function getPos(elems) 
{
    var x = elems.offsetLeft, y = elems.offsetTop;
    var curId = event.target.id;
    var hw = $("#" + curId ).width();
    var dw = $(".drop-down-menu").width();
    var dh = $(".drop-down-menu").height();
    var temp = dw/2;
    var tempx = hw/2;
    var xPos = x - temp + tempx;
    var yPos = y - dh - 20;
    $(".drop-display").css("left", xPos + "px");
    $(".drop-display").css("top", yPos + "px");

    $(".drop-down-menu").fadeToggle();
}
```

I am very sure this will work, if still any issue feel free to ask.

**UPDATE** :

HTML - Added one more ul and onclick event

CSS - Removed text-align:center line and changed position relative to absolute.

JQuery - Total Change

Comment: Great! Worked! Thanks a lot, dude... This is the solution I needed.

Comment: Okay, dude, I'd like to ask you something. I've a problem. I'd like to add several links in my footer with a drop-down-menu, but the problem is that the drop-down-menu is not properly aligned with the clicked element. Look: http://prntscr.com/7gz0f8 code: http://prntscr.com/7gz0m6 How can I do to align properly each element with the drop-down?

Comment: I tried it, but it did not work. You can adapt your additional code to mine? https://jsfiddle.net/j9o9399t/ What I need is a system that is dynamic. I would like to be able to use the class drop-down-menu anywhere and that the drop-down-menu always aligns correctly with the item clicked. I would like to also when I click on one item, drop-down-down of the other element is removed and replaced with that of the item clicked.

Comment: @Uptop14 I have uploaded some files check them [here](http://www.divyashah.in/stackoverflow/uptop14.zip).

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery. Update position on resize.

```
var $menu = $('#help-down-down-menu');     
var $trigger = $('#help');

$(window).on('resize', setPosition);

var setPosition = function() {
  var offset = $trigger.offset().left;

  $menu.css('left', offset);
};
```

Something like that.

**EDIT**

Sorry, *don't use* jQuery.

Your problem is that #help-down-down-menu is positioned **absolute**, but *relative* to its parent, which #site-pusher.

Put #help-down-down-menu **inside** #footer-copyright.

**HTML**

```
<span class="drop-down-menu-trigger" id="help">
 Help

  <div id="help-down-down-menu" class="drop-down-menu" style="visibility: visible;">

     ...   

  </div>

</span>
```

**CSS**

```
#help {
  position: relative;
}
#help-down-down-menu {
  position: absolute;
  /* take out everything else */
}
```

Start there.

Comment: I tried that, but it does not work. You can have a live demo here: http://nextgenfocus.com/test/

Answer (score 0):

Place the dropdown elements inside the footer, then add position: relative to the footer element, and use:

```
    left: 50%;
    top: -90%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -90%);
```

to position the dropdown element.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mf8mgw5d/